# How to enable PHP short tags?

Tags: php, tags, php-shorttags

I have a web application on a Linux server which starts with `<?`

I needed to copy this application to a windows environment and everything is working fine except that an SQL statement is being rendered differently. I don't know if this has to do with the script beginning with `<?php` instead of `<?` because I don't know from where to enable the `<?` from the `PHP.ini` so I changed it to `<?php`

I know that these 2 statements are supposed to mean the same but I need to test it with `<?` in order to ensure that the application is exactly the same. This way I can eliminate another possibility.

Thanks

Comment: [Short open tags are deprecated in 7.4 and shall be removed in 8.0.](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_php_short_tags)

Comment: However, the story is [still developing](https://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=155617657127015&w=2). Stay tuned. :)

Answer (score 620, accepted):

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

And restart your Apache server.

Comment: If PHP runs as Apache module, you can also set it in a .htaccess file: php_flag short_open_tag on

Comment: Most lileky in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: @pinouchon, seedeg wrote that he moves to Windows, but Your comment helps me :)

Comment: Use `php --ini` to locate the loaded configuration file (Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/cli/php.ini)

Comment: If you are using xampp in windows then please Open XAMPP control panel, Click on CONFIG button and go to PHP (php.ini) option.

Comment: For php-fpm pool: `php_glag[short_open_tag] = on`

Comment: If you are using `nginx` you should also restart the `php7.0-fpm` service, as explaned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24551932/828193. The command is `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`.

Answer (score 90):

This can be done by enabling [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) in **php.ini**:

```
short_open_tag = on
```

If you don't have access to the php.ini you can try to enable them trough the **.htaccess** file but it's possible the hosting company disabled this if you are on shared hosting:

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```

For the people thinking that short_open_tags are bad practice **as of php 5.4 the `<?= ... ?>` shorttag will supported everywhere**, regardless of the settings so there is no reason not to use them if you can control the settings on the server. Also said in this link: [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: Short open tags are not necessarily bad practice (I'm trying to keep an open mind here) but just because Rasmus et al. decided to provide default support for them in PHP5.4 does not provide justification for using them. Using them might create a dependency which is undesirable later on or cause confusion with XML. Some good discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use?rq=1

Comment: Ian. We are not talking about the `<? echo $var ?>` short open tag but the `<?= $var ?>` short open tag. Afaik XML should not be affected.

Comment: We have a PHP coding test and occasionally receive submissions where the <?= short tag has been used. Unfortunately the assumption that this style is in use everywhere is a little naive and often comes from developers brought up on a diet of ASP. Clearly it is available but its use is a micro-optimisation and will fail on portability grounds, which is a shame.

Comment: @IanLewis I don't agree. The PHP short tag has nothing to do with ASP. The best reason why you would want to use `<?= ` is for templating and I think it's a fairly valid one. Other templating languages like mustache also use short simple tags `{{var}}`. PHP is often used as a templating language and having to do `<?php echo $var ?>` is so much uglier than `<?=$var?>` in inline HTML.

Comment: It's an interesting debate and becomes highly subjective, I don't believe beautiful code is necessarily better than code that shows a bit of the inherent ugliness. My own view here is that the <?=$var?> version looks much more crowded and much less readable than the more open, but longer, version. The link with ASP must be a common perception then as several developers I know all make the same link without prompting.

Comment: This should be php_flag instead of php_value since it's setting a boolean.

Comment: @IanLewis We can use space to make `<?=$var?> less crowed. See official example: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php#example-40

Comment: Interpolation is cleaner than concatenation. `"Hi {$name}! Last login: {$date}."` is better than `"Hi ".$name."! Last login: ".$date."."`. When generating content, you want the focus to be on the content itself. The same applies for when using PHP for templating. `Hi <?=$name?>! Last login: <?=$date?>.` is ugly, but it's better than `Hi <?php echo $name?>! Last login: <?php echo $date?>.`

Answer (score 27):

This can be done by enabling short_open_tag in php.ini:

1.To locate php.ini file,on comment line execute

```
 php --ini
```

you will get some thing like this,

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini
```

See 2nd line from the comment output.The file will be in the mentioned path.

2.Open php.ini file and find `short_open_tag`. By default it is in `off` change it to `on`.

3.Restart the server,execute this comment

```
service httpd restart
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

To set short tags to open from a Vagrant install script on Ubuntu:

```
sed -i "s/short_open_tag = .*/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 14):

I can see all answers above are partially correct only.
In reality all 21st Century PHP apps will have FastCGI Process Manager(php-fpm) so once you have added php-info() into your test.php script and checked the correct path for php.ini

```
Go to php.ini and set short_open_tag = On
```

IMPORTANT: then you must restart your php-fpm process so this can work!

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

and then finally restart your nginx/http server

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: In My Case : sudo service php7.0-fpm restart

Comment: sudo service php-fpm restart will work for any default version of PHP you have install on your box, unless you have multiple versions in which case you must specify the version you are referring to

Comment: Restarting nginx only didn't do the trick for me. In fact, the phpini() function continued showing short_open_tag as Off. I just rebooted the server and it worked. Kind of drastic, but still faster than research why...

Answer (score 10):

you need to turn on short_open_tags.

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 10):

As simple, as that, follow the following steps:

1. Go to `php.ini` file
2. Find `short_open_tag` and set it to `on`

   ```
   short_open_tag = On
   ```
3. Restart the server

Answer (score 8):

In CentOS 6(tested on Centos 7 too) you can't set short_open_tag in /etc/php.ini for php-fpm.
You will have error:

```
ERROR: [/etc/php.ini:159] unknown entry 'short_open_tag'
ERROR: Unable to include /etc/php.ini from /etc/php-fpm.conf at line 159
ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php-fpm.conf'
ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

You must edit config for your site, which can found in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
And write at end of file:

```
php_value[short_open_tag] =  On
```

Comment: Had to do this on a Debian Jessie. This might apply to all PHP5-FPM installs actually.

Comment: That's because you don't include `php.ini` into `php-fpm.conf`.

Comment: @miken32 , there no way to include php.ini into php-fpm.conf.
Your comment could confuse the reader.
The answer was written eight years ago, I think you shouldn’t have commented on it, the answer might be out of date.

Comment: To say "you can't set short_open_tag in /etc/php.ini for php-fpm" is wrong, and it was wrong 8 years ago. This is in your output: "Unable to include /etc/php.ini from /etc/php-fpm.conf at line 159" which means you were trying to include php.ini into php-fpm.conf.

Comment: @miken32 ,  You’re right, it wasn’t that, I’d forgotten what was here eight years ago.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `Ubuntu` with `Apache+php5`, then on current versions there are 2 places where you need to change to `short_open_tag = On`

1. `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` - this is for the pages loaded through your web server (Apache)
2. `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` - this configuration is used when you launch your php files from command line, like: `php yourscript.php` - that goes for manually or cronjob executed php files directly on the server.

Answer (score 6):

if you edit your php.ini file, remember to restart your service (apache2, etc) for the edits to php.ini to take effect

Answer (score 6):

For Wamp Server users there is easier way:
You may enable that setting simply (left) click once on the WampServer icon, choose PHP -> PHP settings -> short open tag. Wait for a second, then WampServer will automatically restart your PHP and also its web service.

originally from: http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3149

Answer (score 5):

```
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
;short_open_tag=Off   <--Comment this out
; XAMPP for Linux is currently old fashioned
short_open_tag = On   <--Uncomment this
```

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the following steps:

1-> Go to `php.ini` file inside `/etc/php/7.3/apache2` or inside your `PHP version` and

2-> Find `short_open_tag` and set it to `On` and removing `;` from starting.

```
short_open_tag = On
```

3-> Restart the server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

if using xampp, you will notice the php.ini file has twice mentioned short_open_tag . Enable the second one to short_open_tag = On . The first one is commented out and you might be tempted to uncomment and edit it but it is over-ridden by a second short_open_tag

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xampp in windows then please do following

1. Open XAMPP control panel.
2. Click on CONFIG button.
3. Go to PHP (php.ini) option.

Find short_open_tag using ctrl+f utility

You will found `;short_open_tag`

kindly remove the semicolon **(;)** from line.

and keep it as `short_open_tag = on`

Finally, restart your Apache server

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "s/short_open_tag = .*/short_open_tag = On/" /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

That works on php7.2 on ubuntu 16, same answer as above by Bradley Flood, although the directory in which the config file is stored has changed.

Also you can change the version in the php string to match your currently installed version.

Answer (score 0):

For docker  add this step to Dockerfile

```
  ARG phpIniPath=/path/to/your/php.ini

  RUN sed -i -e 's/^short_open_tag\s*=.*/short_open_tag = On/' $phpIniPath
```

Answer (score -1):

To enable short_open_tag for a particular domain with php-fpm, you must edit :

> /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/xxxxxxxxxx.conf

Where xxxxx is the socket number of the domain.

And add : php_value[short_open_tag] =  On

Answer (score -1):

```
 short_open_tag = On
```

in `php.ini` 
And restart your Apache Server.

Answer (score -2):

I'v Changed the short_open_tag Off to On on my  aws centos 7 instance and php7(PHP 7.0.33 (cli) (built: Dec  6 2018 22:30:44) ( NTS )), but its not reflecting the php info page and the code. So  I refer may docs and find a solution on my case. Add an extra line after the short_open_tag   as **asp_tags = On** after that restart Apache It works on the code and I go the output correctly

php.ini file

> ```
> engine = On
>
> ; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
> ; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It is
> ; generally recommended that <?php and ?> should be used and that this feature
> ; should be disabled, as enabling it may result in issues when generating XML
> ; documents, however this remains supported for backward compatibility reasons.
> ; Note that this directive does not control the <?= shorthand tag, which can be
> ; used regardless of this directive. 
> ; Default Value: On   
> ; Development Value: Off     
> ; Production Value: Off  
> ; http://php.net/short-open-tag
>
> short_open_tag = On
>
> ; Allow ASP-style <% %> tags   
> ; http://php.net/asp-tags
> asp_tags = On
> ```

Answer (score -5):

Set the `asp_tags = On` and `short_open_tag = On` in both the files `\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini` and `\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.ini`  and then restart the apache server.

Comment: asp is most probably a typo.  Why can't the community show just a little mercy for @kal?