# Enable short open tag without php.ini file

Tags: php, php-shorttags

Can I enable PHP short tags without touching any configuration files?

Answer (score 28):

You should be able to change it in your .htaccess file if it wasn't locked down

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value short_open_tag 1
</IfModule>
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php for more details

Answer (score 4):

I think the `short_open_tag` can't be modified with ini_set().

Comment: "`short_open_tag` is marked as PHP_INI_PERDIR in PHP <5.3.0, which means you can't change it with `ini_set()`" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633301/cannot-turn-off-short-open-tag-with-ini-set

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to an .htaccess but not the php.ini, simply add this to .htaccess in root of the php app you are planning on running:

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this previous Questions:
[How to enable PHP short tags - Manual Setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

You can use [ini_set function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) for setting programmatically

**Revised:**
I try using **ini_set function** to configure it but failed. You can check previous questions for better answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add into your .htaccess file,

```
php_value short_open_tag 1
```