# PHP enable <?= ?>

Tags: php, linux, configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable PHP short tags ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)
>   [Enable short open tags without php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287076/enable-short-open-tag-without-php-ini-file)

Hey,

I never used that in php (as I never needed it) but currently I'm working with another php programmer and he uses it. So I don't want to end up rewriting his code all the time just to make it work on my machine. How should I enable this in php ? Probably it's something in the php.ini ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should put in php.ini:

`short_open_tag=on`