# Cannot turn off short_open_tag with ini_set

Tags: configuration, php

I'm embedding a javascript syntax highlighter to a PHP script that reads source file and echos it back. The js highlighter has this string on one line:

`... [z,/^[^<?]+/], ...`

The short_open_tag is on on this server and the `<?` in the string confuses the script and causes errors. I cannot turn off in php.ini or elsewhere.

I have used `ini_set('short_open_tag', '0');` in the same script, but it does not take effect. What could be the problem?

**Edit**

In the end, I used what Col Shrapnel suggested in a comment:
I changed `[z,/^[^<?]+/],` to `[z,/^[^<?php echo '<' .'?'; ?>]+/],`

Comment: Doing it in the same script makes no sense. Don't you think?

Comment: `a javascript syntax highlighter` means "PHP code to highlight JS code" or "JS code to highlight PHP code"?

Comment: ini_set may has been disabled on the server, Contact your server administrator to make sure it's enable.

Comment: I am using Google's syntax highlighter which is javascript code and highlights about any code, be it PHP, JS, CSS, ...

Comment: @Omid Amraei - I don't want to affect this behavior for other PHP scripts on this server or even those in the same directory, so I need to tell this very script to disregard short open tags and do not take them as *What follows is PHP code*

Comment: @Omid even if it was enabled, `ini_set('short_open_tag', '0');` makes not a slightest sense anyway. It will be executed AFTER the moment PHP code got actually parsed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

'short_open_tag' is marked as PHP_INI_PERDIR in PHP <5.3.0, which means you can't
change it with ini_set().

Answer (score 3):

According to a comment on [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php):

> libkhorse at gmail dot com 06-Aug-2009
>   07:14:
>
> For 'short_open_tag', though it
>   is marked as PHP_INI_ALL in changable
>   column, you should  note the
>   CHANGE_LOG column also:
>
> PHP_INI_ALL                in PHP <=
>   4.0.0. PHP_INI_PERDIR            in PHP < 5.3.0
>
> So as of 4.0, it will not work if you
>   wanna use ini_set('short_open_tag') to
>   change it's value on the fly.

Try using `.htaccess` instead:

```
php_flag short_open_tag off
```

Comment: Although I said I couldn't change the setting in other ways, some answers prescribe the use of `.htaccess`. I should have explained the why. On a side note, I don't understand why this setting is changed to PHP_INI_PERDIR as this is a legitimate use case now impossible.

Comment: @Majid: I don't really see the use case. The highlighter may just as easily contain the text "<?php". Make it so that it doesn't matter. `short_open_tag` **should be off on your server anyway**.

Comment: Well it simply doesn't! The method I'm using now would have taken care of that if it did: `blah blah <?php ...` -> `blah blah <?php echo '<' . '?php'; ?> ...`.

Comment: @Majid: I have no idea what you mean, or what "blah" is supposed to represent. Anyway, you have your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I see no connection between your highlighter and turning short open tags off.

If some of your code gets confused with short tags, you have to **rewrite your code manually**, replacing short tags with long ones. Or at least run some code to do it.
But no configuration setting will do it for you.

Also, I see no way for JavaScript code to read PHP file *source* with all these whatever short or long tags.

It seems your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Here is the connection: A littral short open tag exists in the highlighter js. Since this js is embedded in the PHP script it is part of that page, as the short_open_tag is on, PHP thinks what follows the short open tag is PHP code, whereas it is not, and it tries to parse what it believes to be PHP code and outputs a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']' error. If I could turn short_open_tag off, the issue would be solved.

Comment: @Majid that makes sense. But why you're placing that js.code into PHP file instead of calling it using `<script src>`?

Comment: Thanks Col, reading the answers, now I think this is the only solution left.

Comment: @Majid not the only, you can actually open PHP tag and make this statement being printed in PHP, like this: `[z,/^[^<?php echo "<?"?>]+/]` but script src would be the best solution anyway, that's general way of including js files into HTML pages, makes browser able to cache it.

Comment: Ha ha! Really! I was on my way to (grumpily) change the embed to script source, but this saved me. I agree completely that that is the preferred way, but I have a good reason to go the embed way this once.