# Set php.ini values programmatically

Tags: php, configuration

Is it possible to set `php.ini` values from within PHP? Optimally with a limited scope?

Background: I want to force-allow `short_open_tag` for the duration of an `include` command to facilitate content writers’ jobs. The actual PHP web application uses long tags throughout (well, one at the beginning and one at the end, really) but for the content files I’d like to enable the more convenient shortcuts.

The content files are then rendered by a combination of output buffering and `require`, and the result of this is used to fill out a view-specific template. (I know about template engines such as Smarty but I don’t want to use them here.)

The [`php.ini` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.php) unfortunately doesn’t tell how to query/set the configuration values.

Comment: `short_open_tag` specifically can [not be changed at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633301/cannot-turn-off-short-open-tag-with-ini-set) anymore.

Comment: @mario: as of php 5.3.0, [it can](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Comment: @Cicada: Ah, ok. Got that mixed up. (It's a dead feature to me when it only works on a fifth of deployment targets.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just change the tags (e.g. `perl -e "s/<\?\s/<\?php /g;" -pi.save $(find DirectoryName -type f)` )

Comment: @symcbean Apart from the fact that it’s not quite that straightforward (what about `<?` when it occurs in a string?), I **want** to use short tags here, to help the content writers. Short tags are in general *a good thing* (apart from the fact that PHP, as usual, botched it up by using something that is ambiguous when used together with XML).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) do the job ?

```
string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )
```

There's also [ini_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) for querying the configuration.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Although as Mario mentions in a comment above, this unfortunately doesn’t work for `short_open_tag` in PHP v5.2 (which I’m unfortunately using). So I’ll resort to `.htaccess` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically set some of the PHP configuration variables using `ini_set()`: http://php.net/ini_set. Note that not all variables can be changed at run-time, but `short_open_tag` can be. See here for more details on what can and can't be changed in which situations: http://php.net/ini.core.php.

Answer (score 1):

if you used ini_set able to control php.ini settings programaticaly

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php