# where is php.ini file located in AndroPHP apps

Tags: php, android

I am using AndroPHP apps in my android LG mobile. I want to configure php.ini file in this apps. Because, I need to store large video file. so, please anyone tell me where is php.ini file is located in AndroPHP apps.

Comment: its appear strange question for me....  as it tagged php....

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your Operating System

in **Windows**

Create a file checkphpini.php, and it will show your where php.ini is located in your machine.

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

In **Linux**

```
Location of php.ini is: /etc/php.ini in linux
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. In the php info page, Loaded Configuration File section showing the directory path. The path is showing that was  "/data/data/com.ayansoft.androphp/php/php.ini". But the "/data" folder is empty. so, where I can find it.

Comment: that folder is hidden in ur mobile ..don't idea about that ..m just tell about you window you can find your path ..check it nd whatever modification you want set it

Comment: dnt have idea but you can do it programmiticaly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667375/set-php-ini-values-programmatically     check this

Comment: and if you are satisfied than accept it as answer so onother user can get benifit of it

Comment: LG Mobile: Android Version:4.1.2

Answer (score -1):

I have solved my problem.
 step1:
Root the mobile phone.
step2:
install Es file explorer & manager and allow to root permission enable option to show hidden folders. then go to device storage (not in sdcard storage). then path is data/data/...as per phpinfo().

Comment: You should have given credit to @Tufan who really told you *"where is php.ini file located in AndroPHP"*.