# How can we enable php short-open-tag for a single script

Tags: php, php-shorttags

Is it possible to enable php short-open-tag for a single script ??

The solutions that i have gone through mention adding `short_open_tag=On` in *php.ini*

or

`php_value short_open_tag 1` to *.htaccess*

Can't we enable them under a php script like we enable error reporting..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - No, those are the only two options you have.

<strike>If you can't do any of the mentioned methods, you will need a container script that sets the value before including the script with short open tags.</strike>

```
<?php

ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
include 'myscript.php';
```

This will prevent a parse error in `myscript.php` due to short open tags.

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) isn't very clear about this, but apparently this **stopped working** since PHP 4 after which it can only be changed using `.htaccess` or editing `php.ini`. This excerpt seems to imply that it might work from 5.3 onwards:

> PHP_INI_ALL in PHP 4.0.0. PHP_INI_PERDIR in PHP < 5.3.0

But that's **not** the case, as can be seen from answers of [Cannot turn off short_open_tag with ini_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633301/cannot-turn-off-short-open-tag-with-ini-set)

I've lodged a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63585) for this documentation issue.

**Update**

The documentation will be [updated](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/?view=revision&revision=328462) to reflect this behaviour more explicitly:

> ... it's been `PHP_INI_SYSTEM | PHP_INI_PERDIR` since 4.0.1.

Comment: i am afraid but it's not overriding `short_open_tag = Off` under php.ini under xampp 1.7.3..

Comment: tried `ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');` but it's also not working..everytime i restart apache to verify..

Comment: why are you deleting your comments..future users should know the whole conversation..

Comment: @RishiKalia Because I prefer updating my answer instead. Besides, my comments aren't relevant anymore.