# I want to enable PHP short tags. How do I do it?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable the <? to start a PHP script from php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-the-to-start-a-php-script-from-php-ini)

what can i do to enable short tag in my php 5 ?thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set the `short_open_tag` option to `'On'` in your [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

Comment: what about Development Value: and   Production Value

Comment: @Tejas1810: Those are just comments: examples of what you would set those values to in those specific environments.  But they're merely suggestions (and some are very good suggestions, like the error reporting).  You should configure your server to work as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
short_open_tag = on
```

Enable short tags in the php.ini