# My Apache doesn't execute PHP code with <? ?> Tag

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable PHP short tags ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

I am using

Apache Friends XAMPP (Basis Package) version 1.7.3

- Apache 2.2.14 (IPV6 enabled)
- MySQL 5.1.41 (Community Server) with PBXT engine 1.0.09-rc
- PHP 5.3.1 (PEAR, Mail_Mime, MDB2, Zend)

and i am running php files, that i code with `<? ?>` tags not `<?php ?>`.
but the apache server won't execute my code, but if i try with `<?php ?>` tags, the code works. Anyone know how to enable the server to execute php code with `<? ?>` tags ?

Comment: Why don't you use `<?php` then everywhere, the less configuration-dependent way of specifying php code?

Comment: Its best to not use short tags though, they are on the way out, and you will someday have to go and change them all.

Comment: You can enable the short tags, but take it as a sign that you'll have to start updating your code: short tags are deprecated and could vanish in any future version of PHP, leaving you with a large pile of unusable code.

Comment: @Marc B: Short tags are not deprecated, although I agree they should not be used.

Comment: @jasonbar: ohh yeah, it's also answer to my problem, sorry i didn't realized it's existencene before, should i delete this ?
@all: ohh, well, thank you very much everyone, i don't know if it's deprecated, so it's better for me change everything before it's too late.. once again thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see now that the decision was made to leave them in. Good enough. Thanks for getting me to go look.

Comment: @Marc B: They might not be deprecated but that they are disabled by default is a strong sign not to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to configure you `php.ini` fiile and set `short_open_tag` to `1`

source: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: Well, he **needs** to stop using short tags. This is just a temporary workaround until the ability to use them disappears entirely.