# php short tag set to true

Tags: php

In php   how to enablw short_open_tag to 1/true in certain pages?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable PHP short tags ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags) and a couple others. Please use the Search Function before asking: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+enable+short+tags+php](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+enable+short+tags+php)

Comment: @Gordon — not a duplicate of that question as it talks about global config settings, not inside a specific page.

Comment: @David so the answer isn't to enable them in the ini?

Comment: @Gordon — the *question* doesn't appear to be able enabling them in ini. OTOH, I could be reading too much into "In php pages".

Comment: @screenavc please clarify whether you want to enable short open tags for just one specific page or for any pages in your application.

Comment: @David stop misguiding people. There is no reason nor deprecation.

Comment: @David Dorward: The "short tags are deprecated and going to be removed in (++currentVersion)!" meme is a well known as an urban legend that has been going around for years, it's okay it's not true though - it just stems from a confusing, outdated mailing list discussion.

Answer (score 1):

**Not recommended** but, based on the manual for [ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and [setting them inline](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

```
ini_set ( 'short_open_tag' , '1' );
```

… in newer versions of PHP, you can't set this from within the page.

Comment: `PHP_INI_PERDIR` in PHP < 5.3.0 though