# php file with <? ?> tags in XAMPP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable PHP short tags ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Hi

I have Xampp version 1.7.3. While browsing a project it shows error. This is because my php code starts with `<?....?>` so I want to execute my project with both the  `<? ..... ?>` tag and `<?php ....?>` tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You are searching for the [**`short_open_tag`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive ;-)

To indicate PHP it should accept `` as valid PHP tags, you must put this in your `php.ini` file :

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Instead of what you currently have :

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

Notes :

- You can find out where your `php.ini` file is using [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo).
- Generally speaking, you should not use short open tags, as those can be disabled *(you've just seen that)*

Answer (score 2):

Set `short_open_tag = on` in your php.ini.

You could also use `php_flag short_open_tag on` on your `.htaccess` file.

However, **you should use `<?php`** as that cannot be disabled!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it man... `<?php` is guaranteed valid on any server running PHP. As a trade off for the extra 3 characters, you can omit the closing `?>` ... see manual for details.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Comment: not 3 but 7 actually, `<?php echo` instead of just `<?=`

Comment: Hi @Col - <?php session_start(); ?>... come on, man!

Comment: if you're using PHP tags to call session start, you're in deep trouble, bro

Comment: @Col - against my better judgment, I'll bite... How/why is session_start() cause for deep trouble?

Comment: not session start itself but session start called in the manner of some template operator. That means you are either calling session start in the wrong place or using no templates. In both cases you are in trouble. I have thousands PHP scripts of my own and in none of them I have closing PHP tag next to the session start.

Comment: OK. Agreed. I've never used it as I wrote it, but it's valid - for whatever reason, it was the first thing that popped into my head. `<?php include... ?>` would have been a better example; although a few lines into the script your earlier example would rear its head `<?=`. I stick with the full tag syntax because I never have to worry about having access to anything other than the scripts (ie php.ini).