# Is inline HTML valid inside a PHP function?

Tags: php

Is the following valid PHP?

```
<?php
function a($a) {
?>
    <p><?=$a?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

(I know this is not a good idea, just want to know if it's possible.)

Comment: @Neal: Because it's not a good idea to mix code and content.

Comment: @ Eduardo León: If the function is part of the display logic (say, a logic that requires recursion), then it may be a good idea. Depends on the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
function a($a) {
?>
    <p><? echo $a?></p> //echo variable content's 

// <? ?> is allowed only if you have **Enabled short_tages in php.ini file**
<?php
}
?>
```

[Enable short_tages in php.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

```
<?
$a="stackoverflow";
function a($a) {
?>
    <p><?= echo $a?></p>
<?
}
a($a);
?>
```

If you try to run this program using `<?=` this won't allowed it will give you error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO

<?= is not allowed in php for tags <? is allowed if Set

short_open_tag=On

in php.ini
```

[As of PHP 5.4.0, `<?= ?>` PHP tags are available regardless of short_open_tag ini setting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Comment: -1; this is a mess. The (illegal) use of `//` comments inside HTML is strange and makes for confusing reading. The English throughout is barely comprehensible, especially the sentence *"<?= is not allowed in php for tags <? is allowed if Set"*, which I can't make any sense of. In your second example here you've broken the syntax of the `<?=` block from the question by (illegally) adding an `echo` to it; I *think* you're later attributing the syntax error to `short_open_tag` not being `On`, but that's untrue; it's a syntax error *regardless* of that setting.

Answer (score 2):

If [short_open_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) are on, yes, it's possible.

Comment: I was actually asking whether it was valid to use inline HTML inside a function, regardless of my use of `<?=`. And, yep, I do have `short_open_tags` on.

Comment: @Eduardo León: _Validity_ isn't really at issue here, you could even use _asp_tags_ (`<%= %>`) if you've got them enabled. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Seems you could have easily tested this though :) Also try to avoid using `<?` , use `<?php` - it always works and doesn't rely on short_tags enabled in php.ini

Comment: PHP has so many gotchas that I don't trust my ability to find them all from testing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a frequently used format, and doesnt follow a functional code writing paradigm. In addition, adding dynamic strings into a long inline html would eventually include more embedded echo calls, which is slower than, for eample, saving a string, and just adding the dynamic content followed by one echo/print

Comment: in addition, to state the obvious - you cannot string manupulate this type of html printing.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon my experience and experimentation: yes, this works fine. Breaking out of PHP tags and writing some content is equivalent to using an `echo` statement. That is, a function like this...

```
<?php
function hello($name) {
    ?><p>Hello, <?= $name ?>! How are you today?</p><?php
}
```

has identical behaviour to a function like this:

```
<?php
function hello($name) {
    echo '<p>Hello, ';
    echo $name;
    echo '! How are you today?</p>';
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't find anything in the manual to back this up. The closest it gets is in *Example #1 Advanced escaping using conditions* on the [Escaping from HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) page, which shows that it's possible to mix PHP `if` statements with embedded HTML:

```
<?php if ($expression == true): ?>
  This will show if the expression is true.
<?php else: ?>
  Otherwise this will show.
<?php endif; ?>
```

It's easy enough to test and observe that in practice, *all* control structures seem to work fine with embedded HTML, including `for` loops and functions. However, the manual doesn't state this.

---

Finally, a couple of asides about formatting PHP variables into HTML, like the asker does with their `$a` variable in the question and I do with my `$name` variable above:

1. Note that since PHP 5.4, it's absolutely fine to use the `<?=` short echo tag within your embedded HTML. Per the manual page linked above:

   > There is also the short echo tag `<?= ?>`, which is always available in PHP 5.4.0 and later.

   The other answers here claiming or implying that `<?=` is only usable if `short_open_tags` is on are wrong, and were already wrong at the time that they were posted.
2. In real code, you should generally call `htmlspecialchars` on text that you're templating into your HTML, like this:

   ```
   <p>Hello, <?= htmlspecialchars($name) ?>! How are you today?</p>
   ```

   If you don't do this, and the variable you're using can contain characters like `<` and `>`, you risk introducing syntax errors or unwanted tags into your HTML, and potentially open yourself up to XSS attacks.