# PHP end tag in php functions and logic file

Tags: php, standards

Example code in question:

```
<?php 
function foo($x) {
  ?> // <-- PHP end tag in question
  <ul>
     <li>Coffee</li>
     <li>Tea</li>
     <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
  <?php
  return ;
}
?>
```

I am trying to decide if this is an acceptable coding standard / coding practice in a PHP logic file, and what are the downsides of this method in comparison to other html print/concaternation schemes.

Comment: @NSNoob No, [example code is off-topic at Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oh right. Never used it so didn't know. Sorry. +1

Comment: Although I don't like inline html (and never used inside a function), I think your code is absolutely consistent with php coding standard. BTW, this a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940428/is-inline-html-valid-inside-a-php-function)

Answer (score 0):

The logic you provided is not acceptable.

You can do this:

```
<? 
function foo($x) {
$var = <<<END
  <ul>
     <li>Coffee</li>
     <li>Tea</li>
     <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
END;
  echo $var;
}

foo();

// OR You Can do this:
function foo2($x){

$var = <<<END
  <ul>
     <li>Coffee</li>
     <li>Tea</li>
     <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
END;
return $var;
}
echo foo2();
//If the function is only intended for printing just use global variables as you haven't used the $x argument..
?>
```

*Also note that you can't have spaces after the

```
<<<END
```

and before the

```
END;
```

Because of this I haven't indent them to the right inside the function.

Comment: The original works, but the function you provided is a static function that returns nothing but print a string, The logic here is that you can save a string with html and echo it wherever you want. There is no need to do this in a function.

Comment: I had edited my answer. If you want, you can tell me what are you willing to use the function for and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation on [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) which you will find very useful. It explains the difference between single quotes, double quotes, heredoc, and nowdoc syntaxes. I don't want to invite opinion in to this issue, but I don't think the method you have demonstrated is very commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

The function does not return a value, so trying to use it in conjunction with string concaternation techneques is not possible.

For example:

```
function bar() {
   $concat = "Give me " . foo(null) . " please" ;
}
```

will output

- Coffee
- Tea
- Milk