# Is it ok to close php tags inside a function?

Tags: php

I have seen this done in the wild and it really helps at certain times because it makes my IDE recognize javascript or html and I don't have to wrap everything in `echo ""` but it seems a bit weird and I haven't seen it documented so I am not sure if it's a big no-no.

This is what I mean:

```
function return_some_javascript()
{
    $bar = getBar();
    ob_start();
    ?>
        <script>
            var foo = "<?php echo $bar ?>";
        </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Doing this makes it much easier to code for me as I get the IDE features for syntax checking & autocomplete which I don't get if I wrap everything in quotes and echo it as a string (which seems to be the much more popular way of doing things).

Is there a reason that people don't do it this way?  Any security risks or anything I am not seeing?

Comment: It is, and it will work, however it's pretty messy and I prefer to not do it when I can.

Comment: PHP will internally convert this into an `echo`. Firing up output buffering just to capture the content is generally avoided in favour of proper templating schemes.

Comment: Learn more here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @mario I use php primarily for wordpress development.  What templating scheme should I structure this in?

Comment: There is no real use or benefit in using output buffering here at all. There is no function result being used that "echos" output directly, making it hard to catch, which is why you would use output buffering in a situation like this in the first place. This could easily be replaced by having the return statement return a string value assembling the desired HTML output. Should probably add `htmlspecialchars` as the least basic XSS measure (depending where the `$bar` actually originates from.)

Comment: @CBroe The benefit for me is that if I enclose javascript or html in quotes for a string then my IDE treats it as a string and I don't get any syntax checking or autocomplete.  Having large blocks of code in quotes makes it hard to track down syntax errors (my example is simplified but there are sometimes inline scripts I need to use in wordpress that need several different variables added.  If there is a better way I'd really like to know as it does seem wrong.

Comment: As usual duplicates are not actually duplicates of my question and are asking a different question

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Besides the fact that both questions involve PHP tags, the duplicate you've chosen has nothing to do with this question. I'm voting to reopen (but would appreciate you expediting the process with your dupehammer). https://stackoverflow.com/q/5940428/1709587 might be a legit alternative dupe target, though.

Comment: @MarkAmery That was 2 years ago, why the vote to reopen now? Plus, it was [Alon Eitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan) that marked it first as the dupe, I agreed at the time. I'll reopen but if this was in fact a right close, it's going to have to be reduped.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner *"That was 2 years ago, why the vote to reopen now?"* - because I'd never seen the question 2 years ago, and I've come across it now.

Comment: I think this *is* a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5940428/1709587, although that question has a really terrible accepted answer and is much less well-asked than this one. I'm reluctantly gonna cast a vote to close as a dupe of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is inline HTML valid inside a PHP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940428/is-inline-html-valid-inside-a-php-function)