# Php Version 5.3.0 code

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable PHP short tags ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

I am using php version 5.3.0. I am working on a code where the php starts with

```
<?
```

and not

```
<?php.
```

It's not working correctly unless I change all the

```
<? to <?php.
```

Is there any configuration without changing the php version I can do in my server that can avoid this?

Comment: The title doesn't describe the question in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.ini `short_open_tag`

Comment: [There's no such directive.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: an edit of my answer would have took less time tomalak

Comment: You wouldn't have been notified. This way, you have learnt something too!