# PHP without <?php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)
>   [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

I came across some PHP code that is being used on a site. The odd thing is the php code is enclosed like this:

```
<? ?>
```

not

```
<?php ?>
```

How can I get it to run on my server without the 'php' in there?

take care,
lee

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `<? ?>` ? These are short open tags.

Comment: just google or search SO for php short open tags. this has been asked a hundred times.

Comment: If I hand known what  'short open tag' was, I would not have had to post this question to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opening tag `<?` is known as the *short tag*. It is not recommended because it requires a certain setting to function on servers. Specifically, you need to enable `short_open_tag` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: As a high rep user of SO you should not answer questions which have been asked before, you should close them!

Comment: Ah, whoops, I missed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags which is the only duplicate I see. I did find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use but that seemed different in that it was asking whether it was OK to use them or not, not how to enable them.

Comment: @markus What's wrong with answering and closing them?

Answer (score 0):

Configure your server to allow `short_open_tag`s; see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) for details.

Comment: As a high rep user of SO you should not answer questions which have been asked before, you should close them!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<? ?>` with `short_open_tag` turned on in `php.ini`.

[Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)