# problem in shorthand php tag of files in cake php

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I have this simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Cake Blog Application</title>
<?=$html->css('styles');?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<?=$content_for_layout;?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I saved it in app/views/layouts
name it to default.ctp
the output in browser only shows me css('styles');

also I have styles.css in app/webroot/css

it is not working in my browser then I tried this string for begin and close:`<?php echo();?>`
again not worked

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Cake Blog Application</title>
<?php=$html->css('styles'); echo();?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<?php=$content_for_layout; echo();?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found my problem! I used this one:`<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>`

Comment: and this one: `<?php echo $html->css('styles'); ?>`

Comment: so strange that up there those ones didn't work but it works like a charm:)

Comment: You probably have short tags disabled. Or you need a space after the =, although I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I tried it but it will cause error

Comment: how to enable tags then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: Hmmm,I tried it, I enered it in shell and it tells me done in green color but no changes

Comment: interesting!:D I must go to php.ini and change it but I did it in shell! Oops

Comment: I searched my php.ini files I had 3 that I set them all and restarted it but no changes by the way thank you Juhana

Comment: yes!!! It was more than one command in the php.ini you solved it please put it as answer I can choose it as best answer for you;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use full tags as you already found out or enable short tags in php.ini: [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Cake Blog Application</title>
<?php echo $html->css('styles'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```