# PHP no longer replaces {$value} in strings

Tags: php

I am having problem with my PHP coding lately. I used to code like this;

```
<?php
$value = "ipsum";
echo "{$value} lorem";
?>
```

**Output :** `ipsum lorem`

I don't know what happened but like 10 days / 2 weeks ago the same coding gives me following output;

```
{$value} lorem
```

Since this happened, I also can't use `<? ?>` tags, I have to use `<?php ?>` tags. I know tags are related to **PHP.ini** but I have no idea what to edit in PHP.ini to solve my output (echo / print) problem.

**EDIT :**

My problem is not php short tags. I just meant those 2 problems occurred together so I wanted to write it down. Considering this is the first time I heard and / or experienced such problem, I just wanted to write everything down.

**EDIT 2:**

My problem is solved after uninstalling / re-installing (2 times, first one didn't help) xampp.
I'm accepting Jeremy Banks answer as a solution. Please note that my problem's solution wasn't his answer but I had to chose an answer since there wasn't a possibility to close the question with a real reason.

Comment: To solve the "<? ?>" issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: I know how to fix it. I just meant out of sudden something happened to my php.ini and I got problem with <? ?> tags along with output problem.

Comment: Maybe php is using another php.ini. Use phpinfo to see the location...

Comment: No, it is the correct php.ini Come to think once again, I have tried to install newer version of xampp. My system created some small problem didn't want to fix my codes and installed the old version of xampp again. I would think that might be the reason but everything went smooth for a week at least. I am truly lost now.

Comment: I re-installed xampp (2 times, first one didn't work) and now it is working without any problems. I still don't understand the reason but re-installing helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using quoting your strings with `'` you're not allowing `$variables` to be interpolated into it. You need to quote with `"` for that to work.

```
<?php
$value = 'ipsum';
echo "{$value} lorem";
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I still can't use it. (I'm used to use " " btw)

Comment: Is it possible to turn off interpolation for double quoted strings?

Comment: I can use double quoted strings as well as single quoted strings, it just doesn't print variables value. It acts as if {$value} is a string not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

That `<?`  is `short_open_tag`. Look for that in PHP.ini
That output problem, it's because single quotes doesn't recognize it. change it to double quotes

Comment: I know how to fix it. I just meant out of sudden something happened to my php.ini and I got problem with <? ?> tags along with output problem. I need to solve the output problem not this one but thank you for your help.