# <? ...code... ?> vs <?php ...code... ?>

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

I am doing some JavaScript work on a Wordpress based legacy side. I am trying to get the page to run on my dev machine (OS X Lion), but am encountering a problem with code in the template not being interpreted. The template contains some code tags that look like `<? echo($subpage_title); ?>`. Those don't get interpreted. If I replace that with `<?php echo($subpage_title); ?>`, it gets interpreted correctly. I don't really want to replace that everywhere and it obviously works on the production server. Is there any server setting I have to change for this to work?

This is probably a silly question, but I have practically no PHP experience and Google is not really helpful when looking for symbols.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: It's called `short_open_tag`

Comment: Singular, actually -- `short_open_tag`.

Comment: lol...we all answered this withing 10 seconds of each other.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the extremely fast answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable the setting called [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/short_open_tag) in the php.ini file.

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the PHP [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/short_open_tag) configuration value. Turn that on for your dev machine and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

The `short_open_tag` [configuration setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) should be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

Check `short_open_tag` PHP.INI directive.