# PHP: <?= not working / Apache configuration issue?

Tags: php, apache

I've ran into this issue before but don't remember what was causing it. I have a small app that uses the shorthand notation to print variables, `<?=$myvar?>`, but it doesn't seem to get parsed by the webserver?

Any ideas on what might be wrong here? It's a bit weird since everything else is working ok.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo()` and see if `short_open_tag` is on.

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled in php.ini?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable PHP short tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Comment: Thanks for that Mike - I couldn't find it because I didn't know I should be searching for "short tags" so sorry about that. 

I don't mind if it's getting closed, I'm just thinking that people that run into this issue would most likely search for "<?=" issues. If I knew to search for short tags, I would have probably spotted it in phpinfo().

Comment: @Claudiu [StackOverflow search doesn't seem to work with `<?=`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3C%3F%3D), and [Google doesn't post any helpful results either](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+%3C%3F%3D&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+%3C%3F%3D&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...9239.9239.1.9873.1.1.0.0.0.0.37.37.1.1.0...0.0.Rl898Zi5Fdc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=18a8620e2315478d&biw=1440&bih=814).

Comment: I knew about Google, but thought StackOverflow will work with the special characters as well. Voted to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its a short open tag with an echo command (=). since php 5.4 its no longer marked as short open tag and therefore works even with php.ini setting **short_open_tags** set to off beginning with that version. for earlier versions it depends on that option.

more information:

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

you can check that option e.g. using `$sot = ini_get('short_open_tags');`

Comment: I was just about to say the same myself! For reference, http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: just mentioned that uri in my answer with an example on how to check that option in php

Comment: Thanks, this was it! Maybe you should edit the link to point to the English version though?

Answer (score 4):

It may be turned off in the PHP configuration. Did you try adding this to your script?

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Anyway, try to avoid short tags because they're good for nothing except creating a portability issue. :)

Comment: Writing less code is always better in my opinion. And as Hajo pointed out, this is future proof, just as soon as everybody updates the PHP version :) 

Thanks for the advice though

Comment: well <? may conflict with xml files, but <?= should be ok. when php is used as a template engine <?= might be ok, for libraries and class files i would prefer <?php

Answer (score 2):

Not only check for the short_opened_tags  but also be sure that `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php` is in your http.conf file. If its not there please add it and restart your apache server.