# error in xampp server not reading <? code

Tags: php

I have problem in my xampp server php file not work if I write it like this

```
<?
echo " Not Work " ;

?>
```

Work

```
<?php 

echo " it's work " ;

?>
```

the server will not read the content with the first status ,  how to fix it to work with both  in same time ?

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable short tags to be able to use `<?` and `?>` without the PHP bit.

Look for:short_open_tag in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) and set it to:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Then restart Apache.