# Embedded PHP does not execute or render

Tags: php

I have a PHP page like this:

```
<?
... Some PHP code here ...
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            ... Some JavaScript code here ...
            <?= $someVariable ?>
            ... Some more JavaScript code here ...
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The thing is that the code:

```
<?= $someVariable ?>
```

Appears unchanged in the resulting HTML: its not executed or rendered.  However, the initial PHP section executes normally (I verified this fact by adding "echo" calls in the first PHP block).

Comment: Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **full** syntax `<?php ... ?>`

If you have PHP lower than 5.4 you can enable in php.ini shorttag set "short_open_tag" to "On"

From **PHP 5.4** you can use shortags, regardless of shorttags settings

Answer (score 3):

You're using a feature called Short Tags, which is often disabled by default. Replace those tags with `<?php print $someVariable ?>` or [enable short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $someVariable; ?>
```