# How to enable <?= ?> - lamp

Tags: php, configuration, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Quick question how to enable:
`<?="something"?>`

It should just echo:
something

How to turn it on in web server configuration? How is it called that `<?= ?>` ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Do not do that. [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open php.ini file and then set following

```
short_open_tag=On
```

And restart your Apache server.