# apache doesn't understand php in <?

Tags: php, apache, httpd.conf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Don't know how to search this question in internet:)

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
?>
```

works, but

```
<?
echo 'Hello world';
?>
```

doesn't.

Probably I need to change something in httpd.conf, but can't find what.

Comment: [Don't use short tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use). Change the code, not the server configuration.

Comment: Did you look for an answer before posting a question here?

Comment: Slowpoke, is it you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your php.ini file, put this property to on :

```
short_open_tag = on
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because short tags are disabled.

To enable them, enable the setting `short_open_tag` in php.ini

open php.ini search for `short_open_tag` and remove `;` from front