# Drupal not loading PHP on WAMP

Tags: php, windows, drupal, wamp

I am working on a local dev environment for a Drupal site we are building. I am having trouble at one last step, and that is getting PHP in Drupal to execute properly. As you see below, when I view source on the localhost page being executed in PHP the HTML markup contains PHP code that should be executed server side first. I have confirmed the DB is connected fine, and this site runs fine on our production server. How can I fix this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?= $language->language; ?>" lang="<?= $language->language; ?>">
<head profile="<?= $grddl_profile; ?>">
    <?= $head; ?>
    <title><?= $head_title; ?></title>
    <?= $styles; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?= $classes; ?>" <?= $attributes;?>>

<?= $page_top; ?>
<?= $page; ?>
<?= $page_bottom; ?>

<?= $scripts; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Short tags is the first thing that comes to mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: BOOOM!!!!!! Worked. short_open_tag=On

Comment: Glad it helped - but this is exactly the reason use of short tags is discouraged. They're not exactly portable.

Comment: You should def get rid of short tags either way

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled PHP input filter?
Have you enabled short open tag in php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

You need in **php.ini** file edit this line from

> short_open_tag = Off

to

> short_open_tag = On