# Inline PHP getting converted to comment tags

Tags: php

This is the most random thing I have ever seen, but when I print a variable in page using a simple method like:

```
<?= $appCnt ?>
<? echo $appCnt ?>
```

It gets rendered as:

```
<!--?= $appCnt ?-->
<!--? echo $appCnt ?-->
```

I have reinstalled PHP and the crazy thing is everywhere else on the page it is working fine. If I echo this before page load it renders fine, but I even have other stuff in page that is rendering properly.

If I do the following, it works but why on earth is that?

```
<?php echo $appCnt ?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need ot enable short open tags

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: or better yet, don't use them. They're deprecated. Best practice is always to use the long `<?php` syntax. (actually the `<?=` syntax has been reinstated in 5.4, but the `<?` syntax is still deprecated and won't be coming back)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked to see that `short_open_tag` are enabled in PHP? Or, are you using PHP >= 5.4?