# Weird PHP Session Issue after changing PHP configuration

Tags: php, session

So I have a PHP function that sets a session variable as follows:

```
function createSVar($varext) { 
 [...]
 $_SESSION['v'.$varext) = time(); // hypothetical value set
 [...]
 return $output;
}
```

And functions that call it:

```
function someFunction1() { 
 [...]
 $output = createSVar("name1");
 [...]
 return $output;
}

function someFunction2() { 
 [...]
 $output = createSVar("name2");
 [...]
 return $output;
}
```

These function is contained in a functions file. Then I have a config file setup as follows:

```
<?
ob_start();
session_name("mysession");
session_start();
[...]
include("functions.php");
```

Then on my PHP pages these are used as follows:

```
<?
include("config.php");
[...]
echo someFunction2();
[...]
echo someFunction1();
```

My problem is that this setup works fine on two different machines with PHP 5.2.17. On the third one with PHP 5.3.0, it doesn't. For some reason, it changes the previous session values (for the previously set session variable) on each call of the `createSVar()` function. I checked the changelog and didn't see any updates.

Could this be a bug?

Comment: have you compared the ini files for both environments? any differences?

Comment: I can generate a phpinfo() on either environments, but I don't have direct access to the INI files. Should I be looking for something in particular that could cause this issue? There's a lot of info there...

Comment: yeah! it can be quite overwhelming and there's no magic answer.  There are many things you can check like 'Register Globals' (which is obsolete since PHP 5.3), or maybe session.* settings.  You could also add var_dump() and echo() to trace your script's flow or you could set error_reporting(E_ALL) to make sure you don't have any errors.  Also, make sure your script doesn't depend on any of this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php

Comment: Quick shot: Short open tags: `<?` - see: [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/367456?r=0) and [How to enable PHP short tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2185320/367456?r=0)

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is to have the ob_start() called after the session_start(). Session_start() requires sending HTTP headers which may be getting buffered by the ob_start() call.

Comment: Nope. No luck with that change. Like I said, it works fine on two different hosting providers with 5.2.17.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. From what is normally technically known, output buffering should not conflict with `session_start()` in any way.