# can not use "<?= ?>" in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

In coding i always write

`<?= $this->description?>` *rather than* `<?php echo $this->description ?>`

it is little bit faster and easier. 
However, after i started using zend framework, i couldn't use that feature.
so do you have any idea about it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: My idea is that you should probably stop using short tags. Otherwise, you can look for the php.ini file and set short tags to be on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: Also read this discussion on why it's oftentimes not a good idea to use them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: Looking through all the answers I was amazed that no one opted in that [from PHP 5.4.0 the short_open_tag directive does not include the short echo tag](http://goo.gl/N6Pyi) **`<?= $example;?>`**! This is very important as the use of all other short tags is considered futile. Anyway the use of the short echo tag is encouraged from now on. It does provide for a smoother and tidier code-base - esp. in view files. So _for PHP >= 5.4.0_ **`<?= ?>`** can be used **without setting** `short_open_tag`. Please do not use the other short tags in your code. The code-Gods get very angry when you do so...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to enable the `short_open_tag` option in the configuration file php.ini. Short tags are disabled by default.