# wamp server not running PHP code in javascript statements

Tags: php, javascript, wamp, wampserver

The php in the javascript code is coming back as the php statememnt rather than the $_GET value is there something in the config that needs to be changed? This worked on a university apache server but doesnt seem to be in this case, PHP and javascript is working on other pages just fine. The delete works fine too.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  setTimeout(function(){
  alert("<?echo $_GET['deletename']?> Deleted, you will now return to the Artist Search...")
    window.location = "http://www.aaaaa.tk/CI/index.php/about?deletedartist=<?echo $_GET['deletename']?>";
  }, 100);

 </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
 </head>
 <?php

 $artistid = $_GET['deleteid'];

$username="X";
$password="X";
$database="X";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password) or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error()); 
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
/* Performing SQL query */ 
$query = "DELETE FROM fbartist WHERE id =$artistid"; 
$query2 = "ALTER TABLE fbartist AUTO_INCREMENT=1;"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Delete Query failed :".$query."" . mysql_error()); 
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die("Auto Increment Query failed : " . mysql_error()); 

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Is it the missing semicolon after your `alert` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either try

```
alert("<?php echo ....
```

or

check `php.ini` for `short_open_tag = on`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags).

Comment: Yes it was the missing php at the beginning tag, I thought I had done all of those, my bad. Thanks for your help.