# copy/paste from word to html

Tags: html, ms-word

I' can't believe that i'm struggling almost 2 hours with this absurdity:

when I copy/paste some text from my .docx document to Notepad++ a lot of characters are missing and I get '?' (question marks). I've tried to copy that text from .docx to Notepad and when I want to save that file it says

> This file contains characters in Unicode format which will be lost if you save this file as an ANSI encoded text file. To keep the Unicode information, click Cancel below and then select one of the Unicode options from the Encoding drop down list.

Then, I've tried to save it as Unicode and to copy from that new .txt file to my html editor (Notepad++), but freakin problem remains!

It's strange that this problem happens only with few paragraphs in that .docx file. Remaining part of text is copying just fine.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Please Give it a try below ways:

1. Type directly into the editor itself.
2. Paste into Notepad first, deselect your text, re-select it, then paste it into the editor (putting it into Notepad first strips out everything but text, so you’ll probably have to reformat your lists, bold, italics, etc.).
3. Use the “Paste From Word” icon in your editor toolbar instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac), but be aware that this doesn’t always erase all the markup.
4. Use an online Word -> Clean HTML converter like http://word2cleanhtml.com.

Source: [Copy/Paste From Word to Editor](http://www.websighthangouts.com/how-to-paste-from-microsoft-word/)

Or Refer: [Paste From Word](http://kb.its.psu.edu/cms/article/104)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately none of these steps has solved my problem (except first one, but i don't want to type all of the text again). It is strange because one part of text copies just fine and the other doesn't. So it looks like it doesn't have anything with MS Word, it's something with text encoding but i don't know what..