# Curl request returns contents of php file instead of executing it

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

From a website I'm developing, I'm sending a Curl request to a php file (on the same server) that should process the request and return a response. The response I get is the contents of the php file that is supposed to process the request.

It's all run on Ubuntu 13.10 server.

Comment: Nothing to do with curl. Your Apache is misconfigured and not executing PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related with your curl. Rather its related with your php configuration. I am suspecting this problem is related to `php` short tag.

For example your server might have the php code started with `<?` instead of `<?php`. If this is true, then you have to enable the `short_open_tag=On` from your `php.ini` file. Here is more detail about [How to enable PHP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags).

Comment: THANKS! added short_open_tag=On and I got the response I expected! Thanks again!