# Instead of proccessing code of php it shows it as a comment

Tags: php, html, css

I have problem with php code. Instead of show this code processed it treats this code as comment. Other parts of code work properly, only this one no. The second intresting thing is that when I have written *?php* instead of *?* website is even not showing this code as a comment. What can be a reason?

```
<?
    if (((isset ($_GET ["leaf"]))
    && ($_GET ["leaf"] != "news0"))
    || (!isset ($_GET ["leaf"])))
        {
        echo "<a class=\"tuco\" href=\"?node=news&amp;leaf=news0\">";
        }
    else
        {
        echo "<strong><a class=\"tuco\" href=\"?node=news&amp;leaf=news0\">";
        }
    echo "erstellen";
    if (((isset ($_GET ["leaf"]))
    && ($_GET ["leaf"] != "news0"))
    || (!isset ($_GET ["leaf"])))
        {
        echo "</a>";
        }
    else
        {
        echo "</a></strong>";
        }
    echo " | ";
    if (((isset ($_GET ["leaf"]))
    && ($_GET ["leaf"] != "news1"))
    || (!isset ($_GET ["leaf"])))
        {
        echo "<a class=\"tuco\" href=\"?node=news&amp;leaf=news1\">";
        }
    else
        {
        echo "<strong><a class=\"tuco\" href=\"?node=news&amp;leaf=news2\">";
        }
    echo "l&#246;schen";
    if (((isset ($_GET ["leaf"]))
    && ($_GET ["leaf"] != "news2"))
    || (!isset ($_GET ["leaf"])))
        {
        echo "</a>";
        }
    else
        {
        echo "</a></strong>";
        }?>
```

[Screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjz2qh1bt6pokc9/problem.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP short tags are disabled on your `php.ini`. Change `php.ini` to process short tags:

[How to enable PHP short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Regards

Comment: Yes, I had switch off this, but now after switch on it just not shows anything.

Comment: Ahh... Everything good, I needed to refresh this few times. Thank you :)

Comment: Pleased to help you :)