# My PHP site's first page is shown as php code inside browser

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Windows server 2003 service pack 2 installed on my virtual host.
This is my server settings:

- IIS version: 6.0
- PHP version: 5.3.28
- My website engine: Wordpress

When I try to open my site inside my browser, I see lot of php code inside browser. Other pages works fine but the first page is full of php code.

What is the problem?

**Edit:**

- I have this site working fine on my local machine. The error is just inside the main server.
- I changed short_open_tag to On but nothing changed.
- Now I'm trying to remove the wordpress and install it from scratch.

Comment: Are you pointing the browser to localhost, or simply to the file?

Comment: Make sure that pages extension is .php not .php.txt or something. That got me a few times when I set up my page and I created the index page as a txt or html unknowingly.

Comment: no I'm trying to open site by domain url in browser. I saw some parts of page but the middle of page is shown as php code.

Comment: Make sure extension is PHP & you are not breaking PHP tag anywhere around the code.

Comment: Since you say that other pages are executing php normally I would suggest checking if the Greather Than symbol (<) is not replaced with &gt;

Comment: Have you used short tags ? Make sure it's open at server. Or post the code of the page so that we can help you more.

Comment: @Rikesh What do you mean by "Make sure it's open at server"? Tell me more abouth this.

Comment: did you used <? ?> php short tags, this caused me similar problem onetime. but it was an error for me.

Comment: @S.Yavari - Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: @Rikesh Read my Edit please.

Comment: My web server is IIS 6.0 not apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved just by removing wordpress and installing it again.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a problem of pairing tags.

```
<?php Instructions ?>
```

Check each start and end tag. If you don't see an error, try do copy the code in a draft, delete all the page and then reconstruct it part by part to see where is the problem.

Hope this technique will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow all instructions in order to activate the IIS FastCGI module, as shown on this page ?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

Comment: I have iis6.0 and yes. I have another php site working fine on this machine.

Comment: Did you configure `index.php` as default document on this website ?

Comment: What's happening when you put a simple `<?php echo('Hello world'); ?>` on a page on this website, and load it from the browser ?

Comment: Other pages working fine. I have this problem inside my first page and not in all of the page. Just the middle of page has problem.

Comment: Did you check the PHP tags inside this page ?

Comment: Ye I checked theme all