# how to support <? ?> php code embedding in html?

Tags: php, apache

I have to migrate a php website from windows to centos. But I found that so many php codes embedding in html are wrapped in

```
<? echo sth ?>
```

but not

```
<?php echo sth ?>
```

so those php files don't work.

my OS is centos6.4 64bit, and the web server is Apache/2.2.15

anyone help me?

Comment: turn short php tags on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable PHP short tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented, turn

```
short_open_tag=on
```

in php.ini