# PHP Short tags validation in a wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am designing a wordpress theme and i'm using a [plugin that validates the theme](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/)

after validation i have alot of errors;

```
WARNING: Found PHP short tags in file header.php.

Line 25: <?PHP if ($topbaronoff == 'on'): ?>

Line 27: <?PHP if ($topmenuonoff == 'on'): ?>

Line 32: <?PHP endif; ?>
```

I am lead to believe that php short tag was something like the following

```
<? if ($topbaronoff == 'on'): ?>
```

Comment: And your question is ... what?

Comment: can't you just set tags as lowercase? `<?php ?>`?

Comment: Basicly am i right or wrong? if im wrong any idea why these are causing a error? (in the validation)

Comment: @rikpg I'll try that now but would that make a diffrence?

Comment: not sure, but perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: correct, those are not short tags. Why the plugin says they are is unknown - if you want an answer to that you would have to isolate the specific code in the plugin and add it to your question

Comment: The plugin validates the theme incorrectly. It expects lowercased `<?php` tag though it is permitted in any case.

Comment: @thenashone, take a look at my answer. Your Theme Check plugin is wrong about the tags.

Comment: @rikpg you was right changing he <?PHP to <?php worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're using [Theme Check plugin for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/developers/). I took a look at its source code, and yes, the short tags validation is broken there. Take a look at the [PHPShortTags check](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/theme-check/trunk/checks/phpshort.php), line 11: it will only match lower-case `<?php` opening tag, causing a warning for `<?PHP`.

This is a good reason to file a bug report for this plugin. But also I'd like to note that though `<?PHP` is a valid PHP open tag, you shouldn't really use it, as most coding standards deny such syntax.

Comment: Thank you :), may i ask why the coding standards deny the syntax? im only asking to further my knowledge

Comment: @thenashone, here's PSR-1: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/ The first bullet point in `Overview` section states that `Files MUST use only <?php and <?= tags.` I cannot really find the vote or discussion on this standard, but I'm pretty sure using `<?PHP` would break some PHP parsers.