# How to make PHP work with <? and not <?php

Tags: php

I've setup a copy of a live site on my local WAMPSERVER and experience that the PHP is not being executed.

**I suspect it's because of how PHP is being defined in the code,** which is like: `<? $i = 0; ?>` and not `<?php $i = 0; ?>` (not sure if there's a "correct" term for this?)

This is working on the LIVE site, so im just wondering if there's an easy way for me to make `<?..?>` work locally without changing too much?

Wampserver PHP version is: 5.3.13

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: I can easily see its a dublicate and understand the votedown - just damn hard to find when you don't know it's called "short open tag"

Comment: Even you can google it like this **php without php tag**.So it will give something as result and then you can make out from there.

Comment: I'll try and do some better googling next time - sometimes you dont think clear - this time surely one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `short_open_tag` in your **php.ini**

```
short_open_tag = On
```

After that you have to restart the WAMP server for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

in your php.ini enable the PHP short tags to allow.

and restart your apache server.

```
short_open_tag = On
```

It will work

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your PHP.ini and modify the line:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Then restart your web server.

It's not recommended however, because your code can be used only on servers allowing them.