# Unable to make this PHP form work

Tags: php, mysql, forms

The application im trying to create lets me insert data into forms, however Im getting an error message whenever I try to use this code. The error says:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in "insert file directory" in line 92. Line 92 is the last line in the file.

Why am I not seeing the form show up anyways, why is it hidden even if there is an error?

```
<?php

    // Definera en funktion som sköter uppkoppling till databasen
    function connect_db() { 
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db_lab2');

        if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
            echo "Fel vid inställning av teckentabell utf8: %s\n". $mysqli->error;
        } else {
            //echo "Nuvarande teckenkodningstabell: %s\n". $mysqli->character_set_name();
        }

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }

        return $mysqli;
    }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>     
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['spara'])) {           
        $Fnamn = $_POST['Fnamn'];
        $Enamn = $_POST['Enamn'];
        $Gatuadress = $_POST['Gatuadress'];
        $Postnummer = $_POST['Postnummer']; 
        $Postadress = $_POST['Postadress']; 
        $Telefon = $_POST['Telefon'];   
        $Epost = $_POST['Epost'];   

        $sql = "INSERT INTO person (Fnamn,Enamn,Gatuadress,Postnummer,Postadress,Telefon,Epost) VALUES ('$Fnamn','$Enamn','$Gatuadress','$Postnummer','$Postadress','$Telefon','$Epost')";

        if ($mysqli = connect_db()) {
            $mysqli->query($sql);
            print_r($mysqli->error);
        }

        echo "It works<br />";
        echo "<a href='person.php'>Get Back!</a>";
    } else {
    ?>
    <form action="insert_person.php" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
            <tr><td>Förnamn</td><td><input type="text" name="Fnamn"  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Efternamn</td><td><input type="text" name="Enamn"  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Gatuadress</td><td><input type="text" name="Gatuadress"  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Postnummer</td><td><input type="text" name="Postnummer"  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Postadress</td><td><input type="text" name="Postadress"  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Telefon</td><td><input type="text" name="Telefon"  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Epost</td><td><input type="text" name="Epost"  /></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="spara" value="Spara" />
        </table>
    </form>
    <? } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 86 please use `<?php` like below:

```
    <?php
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: It's valid short tag of PHP http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Yes it is valid but it needs to be enabled before it can be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: Yes, go to php.ini and short_open_tag should be set to 'on'.

short_open_tag=on