# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\data_forms\weight_routine_selector.php on line 84

Tags: php

### please some one help me am getting an parse error while inserting data into mysql database through my script

ive also changed its code like to:

?>

still not working... its showing the same error as unexpected ending and thanks in advance ........##

```html
<?php
$conn = connect($config['db']);
if (!$conn)
    die("Could not connect to DB");
$user_id       = $_SESSION['myuserid'];
$user_row      = user_information_row($conn, $user_id);
$routine_names = get_active_routine_names($conn, $user_id);
?>

<style>
    .selection_block{
        background: rgb(119, 193, 88);
    }
</style>



<div class="page">
    <div class="information">
    <div class="title_nav">
        <h1 style="display:inline;">Add Inputs</h1>
        <p><a href="input?weights">view</a></p> 
        <p><a href="input?n">add</a></p>
        <p><a href="input?n_edit">edit</a></p> 
        <p><a href="input">| menu</a></p> 
    </div>

<form action="" method="post">  

    <?php
if (count($routine_names)):
?> 

    <?php
    if ($user_row['help']):
?>
      <div class="help">
        Select the routine you wish to use!
      </div>
    <?php
    endif;
?>

    <p>Select today's routine!</p>    
    <div> 
        <?php
    foreach ($routine_names as $name) {
        $exercise_ids_query = $conn->query("SELECT exerciseIdF FROM tbl_routines WHERE userIdF = $user_id AND routineName = '$name' AND active = TRUE");
        $exercise_ids       = $exercise_ids_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $str_exercise_names = "";
        foreach ($exercise_ids as $exerciseId) {
            $id                  = $exerciseId['exerciseIdF'];
            $exercise_name_query = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM tbl_exercises WHERE exerciseId = $id AND active = true");
            $exercise_name       = $exercise_name_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $str_exercise_names .= $exercise_name[0]['name'] . ', ';
        }
        $str_exercise_names = substr($str_exercise_names, 0, -2);
        $str_exercise_names .= '.';
        echo '<a href="input?n&name=' . $name . '"><div class="routine_selection"><p>' . $name . ' - ' . $str_exercise_names . '</p></div></a>';
    }
?> 
    </div>

    <?php
else:
?>
        <div class="help">
            No active routines, click <a href="input.php?r"style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight:bold; color:white">here</a> to make one.
        </div> 
    <?
endif;
?>
</form>
    
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['input_status'])){
    echo "<div id=\"notify\" class=\"success\">" . $_GET['input_status'] . "</div>";
}
?>
```

## Please help me in this ##

Comment: Your syntax is really bad. Mixing php long and short tags, mixing control structure syntax, etc. Clean that up and your problem will go away. Also consider working in a good IDE, which will help identify these problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have an `<?` in

```
<?
endif;
?>
```

which if short open tags are not set, then it will cause that parse error.

Either you enable them, or change `<?` to `<?php`

More on short open tags:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php
- [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185320/)

---

Additional notes.

If you have more code that you're not showing us and it contains `<?=` then that will also add to the problem.

You would need to change `<?=` to `<?php echo` as `<?=` is short tag syntax for `<?php echo`.

Comment: To OP.  I  highly recommend NOT using short tags at all. Just bad coding practice.

Comment: @MikeBrant *Aye*, indeed Mike. I never use short tags myself. Thanks for the comment.