# I can't find php.ini, how else can I change short_open_tag to off?

Tags: php

I can't find the php.ini but I need to turn short_open_tag to off. How else can I do it?

This is where the file is located
But I have no clue how to access it.
        loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini

What I really want to do is to change short_open_tag to off. I tried to upload a new php.ini but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable PHP short tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags) (Just do the opposite On -> Off)

Answer (score 1):

in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value short_open_tag 1
</IfModule>
```

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Answer (score 0):

On the console:

```
vim /usr/local/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
```

Alternatively, open up putty and log the entire output, then run:

```
cat /usr/local/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
```

copy the putput to a new textfile, make the changes, copy the content and run:

```
echo "" > /usr/local/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini --> make the php.ini empty
```

then:

```
vim /usr/local/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
```

once vim is up , hit "i" and right click , then once more enter, then :

":q" to save and quit

Comment: Wiping the whole of someone's php.ini might upset something else, surely?