# require() not working for file even within same folder

Tags: php, mysql

This works in localhost on my PC, as well as localhost on the remote server:

connection.php

```
<?php
    $server   = "localhost";
    $database = "somedatabase";
    $username = "someuser";
    $password = "somepassword";

 $mysqlConnection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    if (!$mysqlConnection)
        {
            echo "Please try later.";
        }
    else
        {
            mysql_select_db($database, $mysqlConnection);
        }
?>
```

However, while this works in localhost on my PC, it doesn't work on localhost on the remote server (`db.php` and `connection2.php` are in the same folder). I get "Please try later" echoed out.

db.php

```
<?
    $server   = "localhost";
    $database = "somedb";
    $username = "someuser";
    $password = "somepass";
?>
```

connection2.php

```
<?php
    require("db.php");

    $mysqlConnection = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
        if (!$mysqlConnection)
            {
                echo "Please try later.";
            }
        else
            {
                mysql_select_db($database, $mysqlConnection);
            }
?>
```

Thoughts?

Update: Per CharlesRojas' suggestion, I tried echoing out the variables in `connection2.php` but nothing got echoed out. So, `connection2.php` is not reading the contents in `db.php`.

Update 2: I've added the solution below and will mark it as correct when I am able.

Comment: Have you tried echoing each variable? I mean... no clues

Comment: @CharlesRojas Good idea -- I just tried echoing them out. They're not getting echoed out.

Comment: Interestng... what OS is your remote server running? Is it Windows...?

Comment: So try `$files = get_required_files(); var_dump($files);`

Comment: @flyingeagle413 it's Ubuntu 14.04 on a DigitalOcean droplet.

Comment: To install your webserver, did you use the following packages: apache2, php5, php5-cli, or did you install lamp?

Comment: @CharlesRojas Here's what I get: `array(2) { [0]=> string(49) "/var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/test4.php" [1]=> string(47) "/var/www/mydomain.com/public_html/db2.php" }`

Comment: @flyingeagle413 I used apache2, php5 ... didn't install php5-cli

Comment: Is your required file there? I mean your file is `db2.php` or `db.php`? (This is just basic test)

Comment: @CharlesRojas Yes, the required file (`db.php`) is located in the same folder as `connection2.php`.

Comment: What I said should work...have you tried it yet?

Comment: Have you tried using another file and using `require()` (to check if this function fails, which should stops the script with an error...) Not a solution but testing... because of no clues... suggestion: test any possible cause and come back with more info to discard and help more, be sure with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **required** file started with `<?`.

When I changed it to `<?php` , just like the **referencing** file started, it worked fine.

Still, it's not clear why this combination worked fine on localhost on my local PC, but not on the remote server.

Comment: It's because of short open tags are set on one server, but not on the other. http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2185320/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `echo getcwd();`?  That returns the current working directory that's it's looking for db.php in.  Also, how are the permissions set for db.php? What is the exact error it's returning?

PS: The mysql functions (mysql_connect, mysql_select_db) are depricated, you should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) unless you're just messing around.

**EDIT**

> The required file started with
>
> When I changed it to
>
> Still, it's not clear why this combination worked fine on localhost on
>   my local PC, but not on the remote server.

Ah, I totally missed that.  Sounds like your local php config has [short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) enabled, while your server does not.

Comment: good suggestion on getwd(). I tried it, it returned the expected, correct working directory (the same directory as `connection2.php` and `db.php`). The permissions for `connection2.php` and `db.php` are 644. Both are owned by the user www-data. Thanks for the note about mysqli. I was going to update it later. What I don't understand is why it all works on my local server on my PC, but not on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, instead of creating a file with variable names, here's what I suggest you do: create a config.php!

Here's what the config.php should look like:

```
<?php
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_PASS','asecretpass');
define('DB_NAME','somethingalittlespecial');
?>
```

Here's what your file SHOULD look like now:

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");

    $mysqlConnection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if (!$mysqlConnection)
            {
                echo "Please try later.";
            }
        else
            {
                mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $mysqlConnection);
            }
?>
```

Also, instead of using mysql, you should be using mysqli:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql php5-mysqlnd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Rename all mysql commands to mysqli (i.e. mysqli_select_db)

Comment: For php5-mysql, the message is that I already have the latest package. For php5-mysqlnd , I get: `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-mysql : Conflicts: php5-mysqlnd but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: I did everything else you told me except install `php5-mysqlnd` ... still unable to read the **required** file (in the same folder).

Comment: Ok, it may be better if I just help you with this in person, i.e. via SSH, if you are fine with that. How can I contact you?