# PHP error "Call to undefined function" using simple html dom

Tags: php, function, simple-html-dom

I'm fairly new to PHP, and i have a problem in defining a function that returns an array containing a price and description strings.

I am using the "simple html dom" php files that facilitates parsing.

The function i create requires 2 arguments : the link (from which it will grab data) and the id (used to get the proper css syntax).

---

This is the get_product_details.php

```
<? 
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$priceMatchTable=('span[id=our_price_display]');
$descMatchTable=('div[id=short_description_content]');

function get_prod_details( $link , $id ) {

    global $priceMatchTable, $descMatchTable;
    $html = file_get_html($link);

    $result['price'] = $html->find($priceMatchTable[$id],0);
    $result['desc'] = $html->find($descMatchTable[$id],0);

    return $result;
}
```

---

And this is the main php:

```
<?php
include 'get_product_details.php';

$link = 'http://micromedia.tn/barette-memoire/1170-barette-m%C3%A9moire-1go-ddr-ii.html';
$id = 0;

$result = get_prod_details($link, $id);
echo $result['price'];



?>
```

---

Finally i get an error which tell:

```
find($priceMatchTable[$id],0); $result['desc'] = $html->find($descMatchTable[$id],0); return $result; }
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_prod_details() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dom\index.php on line 8
```

Best regards!

Comment: It looks like your file is not being included.

Comment: it seams yeah, but how can the error shows the instruction located inside of the the file: ( find($priceMatchTable[$id],0);... ) ?

Comment: Make sure short tags are enabled or change `<?` to `<?php` in your `get_product_details.php`

Comment: Thank's allot that worked just fine !.
Add it in a answer if you want, to mark it as the proper answer.
Again, many thank's !

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silliy, but is

```
include 'get_product_details.php';
```

really pointing towards "get_product_details.php"?

Disable (//) the function call in you index.php and add a simple echo to your "get_product_details.php" to see if the file gets included.

Comment: Actually it doesn't ! , i made an echo, but nothing shows.
Both PHP files are in the same directory thought ...

Comment: it looks like it's loading properly, but there is a problem inside the function,
if you look back to the error message, it is casting a part of the function,.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
include '/path/from/root_to_your/directory/get_product_details.php';
```

If your trying this in Windows land, it will look something like:

```
include 'C:\Documents\something\get_product_details.php';
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is actually in the tags. I replaced the <? with <?php and it worked .

Comment: Sounds good. If you want to enable short tags, then this is how it is done:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Comment: I really appreciate your help, i didn't know that this was short tag for "<? php" at first