# Why does some PHP code render as HTML comments

Tags: php, html, webmatrix

I just started learning PHP and installed webmatrix to get started. My first test page renders some of the PHP code as HTML comments. I need help determining what's wrong. One include statement works fine while another in the same file outputs as seen below. None of the PHP code withing HTML displays. The file contains HTML and PHP code and is named with a .PHP extension. I do have PHP enabled in the site settings.

For example this line:

```
<?
include "phpinfo.php";    
?>
```

becomes:

```
<!--? include "phpinfo.php"; ?-->
```

05/11: Thanks for all the help. I got it working and learned a few things.

Comment: It seems like short open tag setting is not enabled ,So you need to write it <?php include("phpinfo.php");?>. Just hit a try and check.

Comment: What happens if you replace `<?` with `<?php`?

Comment: Just get in the habit of never using short open tags. `<?php` always.  `<?` never.  You can use `<?=` but that is a different story.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Hi Kerning, If you are happy with either mine or Anant's answer please mark one as correct. Cheers and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should ideally be using `<?php` to open and `?>` to close php statements to be evaluated. You can use short-tags `<?=` and `?>` if you just want to print a value.

Either way it looks to me like php isn't being rendered by your web server. When the tag `<?` is received by the browser, the browser treats it as something which shouldn't be rendered to the end user (which indeed it shouldn't - it should be getting evaluated by your server prior to being sent to the client).

try the following line in your php file:

`<?php phpinfo() ?>`

If this doesn't work then you need to check if php is actually running on your server.

If it does work then as Darren commented below it is likely that you do not have short-tags set to allowed in your `php.ini` file - see SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Comment: Worth noting in there that it doesn't render because he doesn't have php short tags turned on in his `php.ini` file. That's why it won't render correctly, but you still get my up vote for a well-worded answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your file extension, it should be a `.php` file, not a `.html` file.

Hopefully this solves your problem.