# codeigniter php output code not result

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
lang->line($langLine); } return $outcome; } function langW($string, $var1 = FALSE, $var2 = FALSE, $var3 = FALSE) { return sprintf(lang($string), ($var1 ? $var1 : ''), ($var2 ? $var2 : '')); } function langV($line, $var) { $ci = & get_instance(); return sprintf($ci->lang->line($line), $var); }
Fatal error: Call to undefined function lang() in application/language/english/english_lang.php on line 252
```

I moved my Script from one host to a droplet by digitalocean. when im running my code somehow my general_helper is outputting the code to the screen and not running it as it should, and that cause the crash.

general-helper in my helper folder.

```
    <?



function lang($line) {

    $ci = & get_instance();
    $languageVariable = explode(" ", $line);
    $outcome = '';
        foreach($languageVariable as $langLine) {
        $outcome .= $ci->lang->line($langLine);

        }
        return $outcome;


}

function langW($string, $var1 = FALSE, $var2 = FALSE, $var3 = FALSE)
{
    return sprintf(lang($string), ($var1 ? $var1 : ''), ($var2 ? $var2 : ''));
}



function langV($line, $var)
{
    $ci = & get_instance();
    return sprintf($ci->lang->line($line), $var);
}
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  open tag `<?` to full tag `<?php`.

For hosts `short_open_tag` in php.ini configuration file are disabled. 
Allow them and you wont have problems.

More info: [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)