# Trying to use `oauth2-server-php` but token request simply prints contents of `token.php`

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to figure out how to implement an OAuth2 server so that I can handle authorization for my API. I have read through the documentation for bshaffer's `oauth2-server-php` and tried following the step by step this [guide](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/)

But when I run

```
curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost/oauth2/token.php \
     -d grant_type=client_credentials'
```

it simply spits out the contents of the file `token.php` rather than actually return an access token.

I modified the path `http://localhost/oauth2/token.php` to be the actual path to `token.php` as I have it installed.

Has anyone else experienced this or know what could be causing it?

Comment: was this a typo? `curl -u testclient:testpass http://localhost/oauth2/token.php -d grant_type=client_credentials'` missing a single quote

Comment: Have you confirmed that your web server and environment are installed properly?  This sounds like your web server is just giving you the document instead of processing it with PHP. Try accessing another simpler php file to make sure everything is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *short_open_tag* issue.
Does the token.php file start with short tag? If so, change it to a long one (`<?php`) or [enable short tags in php.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags).

Comment: THANK YOU!  I can't believe it but I didn't even HAVE php tags on the page.  Giant facepalm.  Seriously, I spent hours trying to figure it out.  I can't believe I didn't put tags on the page >.<