# Issue with an old PHP form, on up to date php server (php newbie)

Tags: php

I have a client with a website made in php who is newly hosted with us. I have no idea why, but after transferring his website on our servers, the Contact us form's php code is visible to the public. I have no idea why that is, and would appreciate to be directed towards a solution.

(Sorry about the ugly display)

[example of what is happening on the live website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2UFo.jpg)

```
<?php
if ($error) error_message($error);
?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php?go=sendcontact#chkerr">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="formfield1" width="30%">Name</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;" width="70%"><input name="name"     type="text" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<? echo $_POST["name"] ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="formfield1">Phone number</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input name="phone" type="text" size="25" maxlength="50" value="<? echo $_POST["phone"] ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="formfield1">Email address</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input name="email" type="text" size="25" maxlength="100" value="<? echo $_POST["email"] ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="formfield1">How do you prefer to be contacted?</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input name="contactpref" type="radio"     value="Phone"<? if ($POSTED["contactpref"] == "Phone") echo " checked"; ?>>     Phone <input name="contactpref" type="radio" value="Email"<? if     ($POSTED["contactpref"] == "Email") echo " checked"; ?>> Email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="formfield1">How did you find out about Bella Vista?</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input name="heardfrom" type="text"     size="25" maxlength="50" value="<? echo $_POST["heardfrom"] ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="formfield1">Please tell us what you're looking for, or if you have any questions.</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><textarea name="question" cols="40"     rows="8"><? echo $_POST["question"] ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <!--
        <tr valign="top">
        <td class="formfield1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
            <div>Please enter the code in the text field below</div>
            <div><img src="captcha.php" width="230" height="45" alt="Captcha     code" /></div>
            <div><input type="text" name="frm_cap" size="25" value="" /></div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        -->
        <tr valign="top">
        <td class="formfield1"><!-- Verification --></td>
        <td style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="submit" name="Submit"         value="Send"></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
<?php
```

Comment: Have you tried `<?php` instead of `<?`? [More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page) (Maybe item 5 from the [chosen answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/4577762)).

Comment: That was a great suggestion and worked perfectly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace all the short `PHP` opening tags `<?`with the long version : `<?php`

Or you can take a look at this : [How to enable PHP short tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to mark the question as solved :)