# Php code in .tpl files (no template-engine)

Tags: php, apache2

I'm using *no* template engine, but I have an index.php file, which requires my "index.tpl" file. So I can divide php and html code. In the index.tpl file I can use the php short-syntax and everything works fine... I have so say: worked. I had to reinstall my server (my SD-card of the PI was broken) and now this way doesn't work anymore. The php-code in the .tpl-files isn't executed anymore.

How do I have to configure my `apache`, that the code gets executed? Strangely I never had this problems in any installation before.

**UPDATE:**

I just tested: php code in .html-files doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the PHP short opening tags `<? ... ?>` are enabled :

To achieve this, just set :

```
short_open_tag=On
```

In your php.ini file and then restart your Apache server.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (the down-flag is not from me): That's not the problem, I also tried with <?php ... ?>

Comment: Haha, a hater ! Could you try doing a `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` and put the result in a pastbin ?

Comment: omg... I don't believe it. My first try didn't work, because I testet with normal html files. Now I added in my .tpl file <?php and this worked. So I checked again the php.ini files and I saw, that the short_open_tag was set to Off. Changed it and now it works! (Just calling the .tpl file itself works not, also not a html-file with php code, but I don't do nothing of both ;)) Thank you !!

Comment: @Lupurus .tpl files are not processed by php engine, neither .htm or .html. Try to name your templates e.g. file.tpl.php if you want to test them standalone.

Comment: @clemens321: Thank you. I saw that in the php5.conf. That's also the place where I had to add, that the tpl files can't be accessed directly. Thanks for your additional information!