# Why is <? in PHP not working?

Tags: php, yii

I have this code:

```
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'avatar_url', array('style' => 'display:none')) ?>
<a href="#" class="thumbnail" style="width: 96px" id="avatar">
<?php if (empty($model->avatar_url)) { ?>
    <img data-src="holder.js/96x96" id="avatar-img">
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?= Yii::app()->baseUrl . $model->avatar_url ?>" id="avatar-img">
<?php } ?>
```

When I replace `<?php` to `<?` , the code does not work and the browser shows an error.

> PHP notice Undefined variable: class

Maybe I missed an extension in PHP?

Comment: I don't see `$class` in your code anywhere.. Also I don't see `< ?php`, or `< ?`..

Comment: You need a semicolon (`;`) after your `echo` statement. Also, don't use `<?`. Just use `<?php`.

Comment: sorry, i edited my questions, i'm newbie in PHP and i can't find solution from Google :D

Comment: Why are you trying to `replace < ?php to < ?`? Is there a specific instance in your code sample that you're trying to do this with? And what is the outcome that you're expecting?

Comment: My problem is why this code when use with <? , it working in some situation but it not working in my server, when i replace <? by <?php, everything fine, So my question is in PHP i can write <? instead of <?php

Comment: What PHP versions are you using on each server? Maybe this will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags.

Comment: @EdCottrell the `;` isn't needed with the `?>` at the end of the line I thought.

Comment: @chris85 unless I'm mistaken, that isn't true with some older versions of PHP. In any case, leaving it off is bad practice, for sure.

Comment: Describe `it working in some situation but it not working in my server`. In what scenario does it work?

Comment: i deploy with WAMPP in window server, it working, but in linux server it not working :(

Comment: Both servers are running the same PHP version?

Comment: tks for your help, i missing configure short_open_tag in php.ini, Now everything ok

Comment: Was the answer that your other server is running PHP < 5.4 and the `<?=` needed the short tag directive?

Comment: No, short_open_tag in my linux server is Off, i must set On , every thing ok

Comment: `<?=` is valid in PHP 5.5 with the short tag directive off. I think you should get both servers running the same version. `5.4.0 The tag <?= is always available regardless of the short_open_tag ini setting.` http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to enable `short_open_tag` in your php.ini.
Find the line `short_open_tag` in your php.ini and set the value to `1`:

```
short_open_tag = 1
```

After you make the change, restart your web server.

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

> **short_open_tag**
>
> Tells PHP whether the short form (`<? ?>`) of PHP's open tag should be allowed. If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this option in order to use `<?xml ?>` inline. Otherwise, you can print it with PHP, for example: `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>`. Also, if disabled, you must use the long form of the PHP open tag (`<?php ?>`).

Answer (score 3):

In PHP5 `<?` is not allowed any more. We always should use `<?php`. By the way you can do this doing some tricks. But `<?php` is a good practice so don't leave it.

Answer (score 2):

Although technically `<?` can be used with PHP it's [considered best practice](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) to always use `<?php` instead.