# Is it the proper way to mix CSS DIV with input form in PHP?

Tags: php, css

My code displays this:

[image]

but I am not sure if I implemented the div and input form mixing properly.

Could you please comment if I am doing this in the correct way?

CSS:

```
.newstuff
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;  
}

.newstuff.left 
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 15%;
    vertical-align: middle;   
    background: red;
}

.newstuff.center 
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 35%;
    vertical-align: middle;   
    background: green;
}

.newstuff.right 
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 35%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: yellow;
}

.buttontest
{
    float: left;    
    width: 35%;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

echo "<head>";
echo '    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">';
echo "</head>";
echo '<body>';
echo '<div class="newstuff">';
echo '  <form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post" name="auth_form">';
echo '<div class="newstuff left">';
echo '    <input type="text" name="data1" placeholder="This is left">';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="newstuff center">';
echo '<textarea name="centertext" rows="5" cols="50" maxlength="255" placeholder="This is center"></textarea>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="newstuff right">';
echo '    <input type="text" name="data3" placeholder="This is right">';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="buttontest">';
echo '    <input type="submit" name="test" value="Testing">';
echo "  </form>";
echo '</div>';
echo "</body>";
?>
```

Comment: Don't use echos like this. Try separating php from html/views. Check out Twig extension or any other similar templating solution for php, you will love it.

Comment: This is just perfect, that is what php was designed for !

Comment: Haha, @MathijsSegers, +1, you made my day!

Comment: While this question is highly opinionated there are several things that can be improved. Questions like this are what [codereview.se] was made for.

Comment: Tass, the simplest thing you can do - to get rid of `echo`es, and to put everything you had outside of PHP tag, so interpreter simply will output everything to stdout.

Comment: I know about the echos, but what about the way I use div and input form together ? How is it done correctly if I am allowed to use only PHP built in functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely not the proper way of mixing.

Try using template engines for PHP, here are the possible options for you to start:

1. [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)
2. [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)
3. [Others](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines/)

---

As the compromise, which I'd not recommend to use in long run, is to use **[Alternative syntax for control structures in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)** and [short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags), which I found useful exactly for the *trivial* templates, when there's need to involve template engines.

Comment: Farside: thank you. Unfortunately for this project I can only php built in functions, no external modul can be used.

Comment: I'd propose to change the project or the workplace :) I can't imagine any serious reasons why you can't use other classes within PHP from libraries. It's waste to make output via echo-es like that.

Comment: @TassMark, find out my updated answer, regarding short tags, but I'd not recommend, as it's just the compromise for your case.