# Kohana 3.3 view foreach not outputting array

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

I'm studying Kohana 3.3 using very simple and basic examples from Internet.

My controller :

class Controller_Index extends Controller_Template {

```
public $template='v_index';

public function action_index()
{

    $this->template->title='Online store';
    $this->template->content='Homepage';
}

public function action_catalog()
{
    $title='Products catalog';
    $products = array(
        'Product 1'=>100,
        'Product 2'=>200,
    );

    $this->template->title='Online products store';

    $this->template->content=View::factory('v_catalog')
        ->bind('products',$products)
        ->bind('product',$product)
        ->bind('cost',$cost)
        ->bind('title',$title);
}
```

}

My view v_index.php

```
 <h1><?=$title;?></h1>
 <hr>
 <p><?=$content;?></p>
```

My view v_catalog.php:

```
 <h2><?=$title?></h2>

 <? foreach ($products as $product=>$cost): ?>
     <p><?=$product?><strong><?=$cost?></strong></p>
 <? endforeach; ?>
```

When I go to http://localhost/kohana/index/catalog browser outputs two titles: Online store and product catalog ok. But in the place the foreach circle is located it outputs

```
 $cost): ?>
```

What am I doing wrong? Can't I loop through this array? Or maybe my syntax is wrong? Would be appreciate for help with my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because *short_open_tag* option in PHP is disabled. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags) you have details how to enable this options. After that you can use:

```
<? ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this code it's better to use full syntax

```
 <?php ?>
```

Instead of

```
 <? ?>
```

I tried to change the code to:

```
 <?php foreach ($products as $product=>$cost): ?>
     <p><?=$product?><strong><?=$cost?></strong></p>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And now it works just fine.