# WordPress Duplicate issue

Tags: wordpress

I just duplicated my WordPress website hosting to cloud server but it is not working correct. What can problem be?

http://185.73.39.210/

I checked db connection again and again. Db name, user, password are not incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of that page, I see `<?`, which means your new server doesn't recognise the short form of the PHP opening tag.  Either find that piece of code and change it to `<?php`, or (if you can change your PHP settings), [enable short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags).

Comment: I could not find php.ini. Can you help me? Where is it located?

Comment: Sorry, just saw your comment,  Did you take a look at the question I linked?  It's discussed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18443722/1714)